# Помогите исправить код на С++

Tags: c++, структуры-данных, олимпиада, анализ

Игра в пьяницу
В игре в пьяницу карточная колода раздаётся поровну двум игрокам. Далее они вскрывают по одной верхней карте, и тот, чья карта старше, забирает себе обе вскрытые карты, которые кладутся под низ его колоды. Тот, кто остаётся без карт, — проигрывает.

Для простоты будем считать, что все карты различны по номиналу, а также что самая младшая карта побеждает самую старшую карту ("шестёрка бьёт туза").

Игрок, который забирает себе карты, сначала кладёт под низ своей колоды карту первого игрока, затем карту второго игрока (то есть карта второго игрока оказывается внизу колоды).

Напишите программу, которая моделирует игру в пьяницу и определяет, кто выигрывает. В игре участвуют 10 карт, имеющих значения от 0 до 9, большая карта побеждает меньшую, карта со значением 0 побеждает карту 9.

Входные данные

Программа получает на вход две строки: первая строка содержит 5 чисел, разделённых пробелами, — номера карт первого игрока, вторая — аналогично 5 карт второго игрока. Карты перечислены сверху вниз, то есть каждая строка начинается с той карты, которая будет открыта первой.

Выходные данные

Программа должна определить, кто выигрывает при данной раздаче, и вывести слово first или second, после чего вывести количество ходов, сделанных до выигрыша. Если на протяжении 106 ходов игра не заканчивается, программа должна вывести слово botva.

Примеры
Ввод
Вывод
1 3 5 7 9
2 4 6 8 0

second 5

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<deque>
 
using namespace std;
 
int main(){
    freopen("open","r",stdin);
    int a[6],b[6];
    deque<int> d,d1;
    for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
        cin>>a[i]>>b[i];
        d.push_back(a[i]);
        d1.push_back(b[i]);
    }
    int n=0;
    while(!d.empty() || !d1.empty()){
        int x=d.front();
        int y=d1.front();
        d.pop_front();
        d1.pop_front();
        if(n>1000000){
            cout<<"botva";
            return 0;
        }
        else{
        if((x==0 && y==9))   {
            d.push_back(x);
            d.push_back(y);
        }
        else
        if(x==9 && y==0){
            d1.push_back(y);
            d1.push_back(x);
        }
        else{
            
            if(x>y){
                d.push_back(x);
                d.push_back(y);
            }
            if(x<y){
                d1.push_back(y);
                d1.push_back(x);
            }
            if(x==y){
                d.push_back(x);
                d1.push_back(y);
            }     
           }
            n++;  }
    }
    if(d.empty()){
        cout<<"second "<<n;
    }
    else
        cout<<"first "<<n;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Как я и говорил, 30 строк за глаза хватит...

```
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N = 10;
    queue<int> a, b;
    for(int i = 0, x; i < N/2; ++i) cin >> x, a.push(x);
    for(int i = 0, x; i < N/2; ++i) cin >> x, b.push(x);
    int moves = 0;
    for(; !a.empty() && !b.empty() && moves <= 200000; ++moves)
    {
        int ac = a.front(), bc = b.front();
        a.pop(); b.pop();
        queue<int> * win = (ac == 0 && bc == N-1) ? &a : 
                           (bc == 0 && ac == N-1) ? &b : 
                           (ac > bc) ? &a : &b;
        win->push(ac); win->push(bc);
    }
    if (a.empty()) cout << "second " << moves << endl;
    else if (b.empty()) cout << "first " << moves << endl;
    else cout << "botva\n";
}
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, Harry! Не подскажите, [как можно решить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1146108/Помогите-пожалуйста-исправить-код-на-python) эту же задачу, только на Python?

Comment: @DaniilSavinov Увы, тут я не помощник, в Python я знаю только азы..