# Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить код на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, очередь, проверка

Всем здравствуйте! Длительное время пытался решить одну задачу.

**Игра в пьяницу**

**Условие:**
В игре в пьяницу карточная колода раздаётся поровну двум игрокам. Далее они вскрывают по одной верхней карте, и тот, чья карта старше, забирает себе обе вскрытые карты, которые кладутся под низ его колоды. Тот, кто остаётся без карт, — проигрывает.

Для простоты будем считать, что все карты различны по номиналу, а также что самая младшая карта побеждает самую старшую карту ("шестёрка бьёт туза").

Игрок, который забирает себе карты, сначала кладёт под низ своей колоды карту первого игрока, затем карту второго игрока (то есть карта второго игрока оказывается внизу колоды).

Напишите программу, которая моделирует игру в пьяницу и определяет, кто выигрывает. В игре участвуют 10 карт, имеющих значения от `0` до `9`, большая карта побеждает меньшую, карта со значением `0` побеждает карту `9`.

**Входные данные:**
Программа получает на вход две строки: первая строка содержит 5 чисел, разделённых пробелами, — номера карт первого игрока, вторая — аналогично 5 карт второго игрока. Карты перечислены сверху вниз, то есть каждая строка начинается с той карты, которая будет открыта первой.

**Выходные данные:**
Программа должна определить, кто выигрывает при данной раздаче, и вывести слово `first` или `second`, после чего вывести количество ходов, сделанных до выигрыша. Если на протяжении `10**6` ходов игра не заканчивается, программа должна вывести слово `botva`.

**Примеры:**
*Ввод:*

```
1 3 5 7 9
2 4 6 8 0
```

*Вывод:*

```
second 5
```

Мой код проходит всего лишь 2 из 10 тестов, на 7 из которых был выдан неверный ответ, на 1 — превышено время работы (лимит времени работы — 1 секунда). Сам проверяю код — ошибки не нахожу. Помогите, пожалуйста.

**Мой код:**

```
from collections import deque

first = deque(input().split())
second = deque(input().split())
n = 0

while first and second:
    n += 1
    a, b = first.popleft(), second.popleft()
    if a > b and (b, a) != ('0', '9') or (a, b) == ('0', '9'):
        first += [b, a]
    else:
        second += [a, b]
    if n == 1000000:
        print('botva')
        break
else:
    print('first' if first else 'second', n)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что то мне подсказывает, что у вас неверный порядок вкладывания карт обратно

```py
first += [a,b] 
second +=[b,a]
```

Без кода тестов проверить возможности не имеется, но судя по условию так и есть.
Так же это может быть причиной долгого отрабатывания кода (просто потому что отрабатывается какая-нибудь "бесконечная" последовательность.

Answer (score 1):

```
first += [b, a]
```

Изменён порядок складывания карт. Независимо от выигравшего, `a` должна идти перед `b`:

> Игрок, который забирает себе карты, сначала кладёт под низ своей
> колоды карту первого игрока, затем карту второго игрока (то есть карта
> второго игрока оказывается внизу колоды).

**Moё решение**

```
first = input().split()
second = input().split()

for n in range(10**6):
    try:
        a = first.pop(0)
        b = second.pop(0)
    except IndexError:
        print("first" if first else "second", n)
        break

    winner = first
    if (a == '9' and b == '0') or a < b:
        winner = second

    winner.extend([a, b]) 
else:
    print("botva")
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, MiniMax! Ваше решение также верное, однако является слишком медленным: асимптотика операции `.pop(0)` — `O(n)`, что слишком долго для ограничения в одну секунду. Поэтому я применил деки для ускорения работы программы (операция `.popleft()` выполняется за `O(1)` времени).

Comment: @DaniilSavinov Согласен, с `deque` должно быть быстрее. С `pop(0)` не прошло по времени?

Comment: Да, не прошло. Но так решение верное.